# Cannot connect to SQL Server when IP is > .100

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have an MSSQL 2008 Server being connected to from Windows XP.

I can access my database through a vb.net program and the SQL server management studio when the DHCP server assigns a low ip address (i.e. `192.168.0.3` - `100`).  At `192.168.0.101` the program nor server manager can find the database.

All of the computers can see each other and I can ping the server and the server can ping my system.

Comment: Is the address above .100 being configured manually or via DHCP?  From your comment below, it sounds like it's "live" vs "dev" - care to elaborate on that difference?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like your SQL server has a firewall rule only permitting port 1433 access from `192.168.0.1-192.168.0.100`. This would mean that ICMP traffic (ping) still works, because only a specific protocol is being filtered.

Check the firewall rule on the SQL server and expand its scope as nessesary.

Comment: Mark Thank you for the response.  The server is a developement box and has had the firewall diabled for some time.  See below for further comment.

Answer (score 1):

Try assigning a computer that is not working a lower IP and see what happens.  Also, temporarily turn off the 2008 firewall and see if you can connect.  Check the event logs on both the client and server.  Use a packet sniffer (wireshark) on a working and non-working computer to see what the differences are.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  When the computer gets the lower IP it connects just fine.  I have checked the server logs and there is nothing at all about the attempted connection.  I went through the pc logs and nothing.  I did not try the packet sniffer.  But I did come up with other information.  I have to routers on the network.  When I use my laptop to connect 'live' it gives me an address above .100 When I go back to use the 'development' it asks for the same address live gave it.  The dev router is only supposed to give out up to 192.168.0.50 stop the router from giving higer address?

Comment: What are the gateway addresses and netmasks for working and now working computers?

Comment: The gateway addresses and netmasks are different if anybody else reads this.  As a work around I am currently repairing the connection right after it is made and it always gives a lower address and works correctly.  But it still does not solve the problem.